# Cannot Get Annotations for OWLClass in OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I am using OWLAPI 4.0.1 as a global library from Maven in IntelliJ. I am seeing many examples on the Web for how to get annotations for a class (such as the one in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622694/how-to-get-annotations-from-owl-individual-using-owlapi)), but IntelliJ tells me there is no such getAnnotations() method. Other API code works fine, and I'm able to find classes and properties in an ontology. Has the OWLAPI changed, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this has changed in OWLAPI 4. Use `EntitySearcher.getAnnotationObjects(cls.getIRI(), ontology)` instead.

To search over the imports closure, pass the closure instead of the single ontology.

Comment: How can we use this method to retrieve annotations from the import closure?